# Grouping mongodb filtered results by reference id throws

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have this simplified model:

```
public class Parent
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public ObjectId ParentId { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I have queried parents with a filter on some fields I've intentionally omitted. Now I have a parent id collection. I want to get all children that are `Gender.Male` only for those parents I had obtained with the first query and group them so that I can have a mapping between a `Parent` and `List<Child>`.

```
var parentIds = filteredParents.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
var childrenFilter = Builders<Child>.Filter.In(c => c.ParentId, parentIds) &
                     Builders<Child>.Filter.Eq(c => c.Gender, Gender.Male);

var aggregation = children
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(childrenFilter)
    .Group(c => c.ParentId, g => new KeyValuePair<string, List<Child>>(g.Key, new List<Child>(g)));

var groupCursor = await aggregation.ToCursorAsync();
```

This however throws

```
System.NotSupportedException: Could not find a member match for constructor parameter collection on type List`1.
```

A few small side questions

1. I assume I've written the `childrenFilter` in such a way that it would get executed on the server and client won't receive `Gender.Female` children? If that's not true - what is the proper way to do it? And if I used the overload with `Linq.Expression` - would that filter get executed on the server or on the client?
2. Are the children grouped on the server or on the client? How should I write the `Group` in order for it to be executed on the server where it should be more efficient?

UPDATE 17.06

As per @CraigWilson's suggestion I tried with `g.ToList()`:

```
var aggregation = children
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(childrenFilter)
    .Group(c => c.ParentId, g => new KeyValuePair<string, List<Child>>(g.Key, g.ToList()));
```

which led to a different exception:

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --- System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Expressions.SerializationExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression'.

Comment: Your `Child` class does not contain any defined constructor which will receive the parameter you passed.

Comment: @gypsyCoder how should the `Child` constructor look like? Isn't the exception related to the `List` class?

Comment: I think, this link will be helpful for you problem : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah, that's the reference to the `List` class. Really not helpful at all, though. If you'd really like to help could you be more specific instead of pointing to general documentation?

Comment: @ceco, did you figure this out? Side questions: the Match and Group will all be done on the server.

Comment: @CraigWilson no, I did not. Since I had to pull all the data from mongodb anyway - I just did the grouping on the client side with a dictionary.

Comment: I think maybe had you done g.ToList() instead, it might have worked. As long as you are good to go, though I'll leave it alone.

Comment: @CraigWilson I guess my timezone is quite different than yours, so I apologize for the delay. Thanks for paying attention BTW. I updated my question according to your suggestion.

Comment: If you'd like, feel free to file a bug at jira.mongodb.org under the CSHARP project.